# Is it possible to make an apex:image value variable?

Tags: apex, visualforce

If I have a `Map<Integer, String>` (Integer, Image URL). Could I then have an apex:image field where the **value** attribute is determined based on the Integer in the Map?

```
<apex:image value="exampleMap.get(6)"></apex:image>
```

Comment: This `value="{! exampleMap[6] }"` might work.

Comment: @KeithC That worked great! I was even able to make the 6 variable like so: value="{!exampleMap[exampleVariable]}"

Comment: Cool; suggest you post and accept your own answer (when you are allowed to) so the information is well recorded and the question closed.

Answer (score 1):

I first added the URL to my map like so.

```
cardIdPhotoMap.put(1, 'https://cs14.salesforce.com/resource/1447873253000/AceS');
```

Then I called the particular photo I was looking for like so.

```
<apex:image value="{!PhotoMap[PhotoId]}"></apex:image>
```